# Kotlin Concurrency with ConcurrentHashMap while retrieving and removing without using locks

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to understand `ConcurrentHashMap` and see if I can leverage it w/o adding any locks on my side. I have a `ConcurrentHashMap` with number of books at the beginning of a day.

```
class Z {
    val books: ConcurrentHashMap<String, Int> = ConcurrentHashMap()
    
    fun addBook(book: String, numberOfBooks: Int) {
        books[book] = numberOfBooks
    }
 
    fun doSomething(book: String) {
        val numberOfBooks = books.remove(book)
    }
}
```

The above would be threadsafe. But now if I need to add in a validation just to be sure the book isn't being added twice during initialization I need to add a `synchronized` block just to be sure that I am not adding something like below.

```
class Z {
    val books: ConcurrentHashMap<String, Int> = ConcurrentHashMap()
    val lock = Any()
    fun addBook(book: String, numberOfBooks: Int) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            val existingBook = books[book]
            if(existingBook!=null)
                println("Book exists, BEWARE!!")
            books[book] = numberOfBooks
        }
    }
 
    fun doSomething(book: String) {
        var numberOfBooks : Int? 
        synchronized(lock)
            numberOfBooks=books.remove(book)
    }
}
```

Is there a better way for me to do this. I hate adding a `synchronized` block just to put in a log statement in there.

Answer (score 9):

You're in luck: the [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface has several methods which can help to do this sort of thing atomically, and so are thread-safe in [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

In this case, you don't even need anything exotic, just an explicit call to the [put()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#put-K-V-) method, as it returns the previous value (or `null` if there wasn't one).

So you could simply tweak your first example to have:

```
fun addBook(book: String, numberOfBooks: Int) {
    val existingNumber = books.put(book, numberOfBooks)
    if (existingNumber != null)
        println("Book exists, BEWARE!!")
}
```

…which does what you want without any synchronisation.  (You lose Kotlin's array-access syntactic sugar, but that's clearly outweighed here.)

Other methods which can do complex things atomically are [compute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-), [merge()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-), [putIfAbsent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-), [replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#replace-K-V-), and many more; it's worth taking a look through the class so you can recognise situations where they'd come in useful.  As you clearly know, synchronization can bring a hefty performance penalty, so if you can avoid it without sacrificing safety, it can be a big win.